# How to only iterate through the first 20 batches per epoch using keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I would like to fit a keras model but instead of running through all the batches in each epoch, I want to shuffle the whole training dataset (at the start of each epoch) then train *only* on the first 20 batches.

I have tried using `steps_per_epoch` but that restarts the next epoch where the previous one left off. What I want to do is, for **every** epoch:

1. shuffle the training dataset
2. split into batches of size 100
3. train on the first 20 batches

Can I achieve this using keras? I suspect I may need to use tensorflow directly to achieve this rather than keras, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: If you use tf.data api, you can do `train_dataset.take(20)`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into how to do that now. Could you just clarify, `train_dataset` is a `tf.data.Dataset` object here, right? So I can also shuffle beforehand with `train_dataset.shuffle()`?

Comment: yes. See the document